# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "key"

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

My code is like this

```
 namespace DiagnosisApp.Models
{
    public class ProcedurePrice
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }


        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int ProcedureID { get; set; }
        public int InsuranceProviderID { get; set; }
        public int ProcedureCategoryID { get; set; }
        public int ProcedureSubCategoryID { get; set; }



        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public virtual InsuranceProvider InsuranceProvider { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public virtual ProcedureCategory ProcedureCategory { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ID")]
        public virtual ProcedureSubCategory ProcedureSubCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "Name");
            ViewBag.ProcedureSubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.ProcedureSubCategories, "ID", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

And in my view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProcedureID)
```

Everything looks okay to me, But it throws an error

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ProcedureID'.
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I suppose problem with this string `@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })` you should specify `SelectList` i think like this `@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", Model.ProcedureCategory, new { @class = "form-control" })` if you populate this list somewhere for ex - in your Create Controller like you do with `ProcedureSubCategories`

Comment: Hard to understand what you actually wanting to bind to. If you want bind to `int ProcedureID`, then your need to include a `SelectList` for procedures (preferably using a view model, otherwise `ViewBag`) and use that as the second parameter of `@Html.DropDownList`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mistake is you are putting it in `ViewBag.ProcedureSubCategoryID` while you are passing `ProcedureID` int `Html.DropDownList()` and also you are passing `SelectList` parameter `null`. A quick fix is to just replace `ProcedureSubCategoryID` with `ProcedureID` in `Html.DropDownList()`  as key in first parameter:

you have three ways to resolve this.

### Way 1:

Instead of passing `null` in second parameter which accepts of type `SelectList`you can do something like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", ViewBag.ProcedureSubCategoryID as SelectList, new  { @class="form-data" })
```

### Way2:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "Name");
  ViewBag.ProcedureSubCategoryID = new SelectList(db.ProcedureSubCategories, "ID", "Name");
  return View();
}


@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureSubCategoryID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

### Way 3:

or alternative is to store it in `ProcedureID` in your action:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
       ViewBag.DepartmentID = new SelectList(db.Departments, "ID", "Name");
       ViewBag.ProcedureID = new SelectList(db.ProcedureSubCategories, "ID", "Name");
       return View();
}
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProcedureID", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're missing something like

```
ViewBag.ProcedureID = new SelectList(db.ProcedureCategory, "ID", "Name");
```

I think you have to inizialize ViewBag.ProcedureId

Comment: This! was what I needed Thank you!