# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'M_TYPE'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my Controller Action

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddDrug()
    {
        UserDB db = new UserDB();
        ViewData["MedType"] = new SelectList(db.mtype, "MID", "M_TYPE");
        return View();
    }
```

This is For Post Method

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult AddDrug(Drug drug)
    {
        UserDB db = new UserDB();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.drugs.Add(drug);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Medicine Type Added Sucessfully";
            return View();
        }
        return View(drug);
    }
```

This is my view

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.M_TYPE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.M_TYPE,ViewData["MedType"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>,"(none)")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.M_TYPE)
    </div>
```

now i wont to insert data from the dropdownlist into database, but it throughs that error

Comment: You need to reassign the `SelectList` before you return the view in the POST method (its `null` which results in that exception)

Comment: possible duplicate of [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key "key"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916642/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Answer (score 2):

When you return the view, you need to reassign the `SelectList` otherwise it is `null` which results in that exception (see also note about redirecting)

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddDrug(Drug drug)
{
    UserDB db = new UserDB();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.drugs.Add(drug);
        db.SaveChanges();
        // ModelState.Clear(); // don't do this!
        TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Medicine Type Added Sucessfully";
        // return View(); // don't do this!
        return RedirectToAction("AddDrug"); // do this instead
    }
    ViewData["MedType"] = new SelectList(db.mtype, "MID", "M_TYPE"); // add this
    return View(drug);
}
```

Comment: Then accept this and all the other answers to your questions where you have commented that it works!