# "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key" Problem

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I need to set "ManagerID" as the "id" from "Employee".(I mean ManagerID and id are linked). I write codes but have a problem. It shows items with dropdownlist correctly but when I try to apply, it says "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key ManagerID"

View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManagerID, "ManagerID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ManagerID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Manager , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManagerID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Add_Department()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> employeeList = (from a in db.Employee.ToList()
                                                    select new SelectListItem
                                                    {
                                                        Text = a.Name + a.Surname,
                                                        Value = a.id.ToString()
                                                    }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Manager = employeeList;

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add_Department(Department_Info department)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Department_Info.Add(department);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Main");
        }
        return View(department);
    }
```

Model:

```
public partial class Department_Info
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ManID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It seems that your problem looks like this [There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key “key”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27916642/there-is-no-viewdata-item-of-type-ienumerableselectlistitem-that-has-the-key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not saving your `Manager` dropdown to ViewBag in your post action because if your request is not validated successfully then you will be returned the same page but at this time you `ViewBag.Manager` is null so it will cause an error.

So you need to add `ViewBag.Manager` `SelectList` also in the post action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add_Department(Department_Info department)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Department_Info.Add(department);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Main");
    }
    List<SelectListItem> employeeList = (from a in db.Employee.ToList()
                                                select new SelectListItem
                                                {
                                                    Text = a.Name + a.Surname,
                                                    Value = a.id.ToString()
                                                }).ToList();
    ViewBag.Manager = employeeList;
    return View(department);
}
```

I've also noticed that your `Manager` dropdown name is `ManagerID` while your `Department_Info` model doesn't have the field with the same name. Actually, this is the problem which produces the worst condition and your first problem encounters.

You need to update your `Department_Info` model:

```
public partial class Department_Info
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ManagerID { get; set; }
}
```

Or you need to change your dropdown name:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ManagerID", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Manager, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Hopefully, It will resolved your problem.